# How to insert value from another worksheet below my last value cell from my test summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently the macro allows me to copy data from my active sheet to test summary sheet but if I were to go to another sheet and run the macro, it will replace the data from my previous active sheet. So, I am trying to insert value from one sheet to my summary sheet and multiple other sheet to be added to my summary sheet. Right now I have tried setting the rng1 to the last valued cell so the data will be captured to the next row but it isn't working and the data copied will be the last value of my active sheet.

```
Sub test()
' test Macro
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Summary")
    Set Rng1 = ws1.Range("E2")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet()
    Set Rng2 = ws2.Range("F2")
    i = 0
    
    If Rng1.Value <> "" Then
        With ws1.Range("E2")
            Set lcell = .Resize(ws1.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
            If lcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data found
            Set Rng1 = .Resize(lcell.Row - .Row + 1)
        End With
    End If
    Do Until IsEmpty(Rng2.Offset(0, i))
        If Rng2.Value <> "" Then
            Rng1.Offset(0, 0).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([7], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([9], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([10], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([12], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([13], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 6).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([14], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 7).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([17], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 8).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([18], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 9).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([23], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 10).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([24], [1]).Address
            Rng1.Offset(0, 11).Formula = "='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([25], [1]).Address
            Set Rng2 = Rng2.Offset(0, i + 1)
        End If
            Set Rng1 = Rng1.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to check
    Loop
    i = 0
    ' Clean up
    Set Rng1 = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set Rng2 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Check on here, there are several posts about finding the first empty cell or last populated cell.

Comment: It would not contain data at the start but it will have the first run of macro, if I run the macro again, it will take another set of data and insert it below the first set of data

Comment: I tried using this method to find data but I cant seem to get it to work, any idea where I typed wrongly?
` If Rng1.Value <> "" Then
        With ws1.Range("E2")
            LastRow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            Set Rng1 = ws1.Range("E:" & LastRow + 1)
        End With
    End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
    Dim lcell
    If Rng1.Value <> "" Then
        With ws1
            Set lcell = .Columns("E").Find("*", .Range("E1"), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
            If lcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data found
            ' Based on the logic of your code in OP, new data will overwrite the existing data on ws1
            ' Rng1 = .Range("E2:E" & lcell.Row)
            ' ** I think Rng1 should be the first blank cell
            Set Rng1 = lcell.Offset(1)
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: Do you know why the data selected is always the last column of my activesheet?

Comment: What's `the data selected`? What's the expected result? 
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It would always take the last column value from activesheet, which is "I". And when I select another sheet to input a new set of data, it will replace all the data I currently have in test summary sheet with the other sheet data. Expected result, e.g. I have 3 sheet, test summary, set1, set2, I run the macro on set1, it will copy the data from set1 and put it into test summary. And if I were to run the macro on set2, it will copy the data and insert it under the data from set1.

Comment: What's the expected output? 
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) `Do ... Loop` causes the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't the Do ... loop start back from F2 and loop through the column when I run the macro again?

Comment: `it will replace all the data I currently have in test summary sheet` is an entirely different issue compared to your original post. Please check comments in my answer. Remove `Rng1 = .Range("E2:E" & lcell.Row)` and try `Set Rng1 = lcell.Offset(1)`.